# In word API after inserting word document into a document i loosing content control

Tags: office-js

i am facing problem while inserting a word document into another document.After it gets inserted it losses the content control for that any other operation is not possible .Please help

```js
function insertDocwit(response,contentControlId)
    {
    //  console.log("dfdff");
      //   // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      Word.run(function (context) {

      // Create a proxy object for the content controls collection that contains a specific tag.
      var contentControlsWithTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag(contentControlId);



      // Queue a command to load the text property for all of content controls with a specific tag.
      context.load(contentControlsWithTag, 'text');

      // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
      // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
      return context.sync().then(function () {
        appData.isContentLoaded = true;
          if (contentControlsWithTag.items.length === 0) {
              console.log("There isn't a content control with the tag");
              ngNotify.set("Content Control with the tag is not Found","error");
              deferred.resolve();
          } else {
              //console.log('The first content control with the tag of Customer-Address has this text:');
              for (var i = 0;i < contentControlsWithTag.items.length;i++)
               contentControlsWithTag.items[i].insertFileFromBase64(response, 'Replace');
               deferred.resolve();
          }
          return deferred.promise;
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        appData.isContentLoaded = true;
        var catchedError = JSON.stringify(error.message);
        if (catchedError == '"'+'ooxmlIsMalformated'+'"'){
            ngNotify.set('The Document which you Selected to Insert is Incompatible with this Document', 'error');
        }
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + error.debugInfo);
        }
      });
    }
```

[lossing content control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Tf9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried on both word rich client and word online the API contentcontrol.insertFileFromBase64(, "replace"). But I can't reproduce the issue you reported. The content control didn't get lost. Are you still able to repro it, can your provide a simplified repro steps?

Comment: it is working fine in word desktop application but in word online sometime it is loosing it content control.

Comment: please check the image i have added.In image first paragraph has control.

Comment: Rest all don't have the control.

Comment: Can you provide the file base64 you are going to insert?